# Close to Cayley's Theorem!

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

**If $G$ is a finite group of order n then $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the alternating group $A_{n+2}$.**

I found this in a book *GROUPS AND SYMMETRY* by M. Armstrong. I can prove this by extending a cycle of order $n$ to a cycle of order $n+2$ in a unique way.

But my question is **Is this also true for $A_n$?**

can't find any suitable example to disprove my statement.

Answer (score 3):

No, the cyclic group $C_6$ is not a subgroup of $A_6$. All subgroups of order $6$ in $A_6$ are isomorphic to $S_3$. In fact, the cycle $(123456)$ is not in $A_6$.

Comment: We can also do this with $C_8$ to see that $A_{n+1}$ does not suffice.

Comment: Hence  $G$ cannot be embedded into $A_n$, Thank you!

Comment: @PronayBiswas Exactly. In general you cannot do better than $A_{n+2}$.